# Error to send e-mail using module smtplib

Tags: python, module, smtplib

I'm doing a code to send emails automatically using Python and a local server (where I work). I don't know why this error happens.

I've tried to connect the server using commands from module smtplib -> smtplib.SMTP_SSL(hot, port) and smtplib.SMTP(hot,port) but both doesn't work.

```py
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('IPfromCompanyServer')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\dbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\dbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\dbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\dbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: have you tried to read error message?)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting to Mail server IP and port number right. And some clients like Gmail don't allow you to send mails automatically without disabling the secure mail transfer feature.

Additionally you could add this piece of code to your program before you log in.

```
 try:
        self.smtp.ehlo()
        self.smtp.starttls()
        self.smtp.ehlo
 except:
        print "No TLS "
 #login here
```

And maybe this link outta help out a little:
https://superuser.com/questions/1292420/sending-an-email-from-python-using-local-python-smtp-server